# Why jquery returns invalid property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following row in my html:

```
...
<div class="jp-container jspScrollable" id="scrollbarY" style="height: 274px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;" tabindex="0">
...
```

in browser console I write following:

```
$('.jp-container.jspScrollable').height()
```

result:

```
410
```

But expected result 274.

in browser console I write following:

```
$('.jp-container.jspScrollable')
```

result:

```
 ...
<div class="jp-container jspScrollable" id="scrollbarY" style="height: 274px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;" tabindex="0">
...
```

How to get 274 in browser console?

### update

debugger shows following values for similar situation:

[image]

At this situation I want to get 105.

I have found following css:

```
#scrollbarY,
#scrollbarY1 {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 410px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem (tested in devtools), please provide enough code and/or an online example.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski for this I show for you second request to browser console.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/vkh1tpo6/

Comment: You have a min-height of 410px. So the answer of 410px is correct.

Comment: Ok @Moob it is correct but how to get real height

Comment: 410px IS the real height, because the min-height sets a minimum height that it will never go under, despite the attempt to set the height lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbarY')
alert(elem.style.height.slice(0, -2));
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkh1tpo6/1/)

Comment: I don't know how to create fiddle for all code. It is jsp page actually

Comment: Could you show how and when you are trying to get the height?

Comment: please check topic - I have added new details

Comment: @gstackoverflow - Try this `document.getElementById('scrollbarY').style.height;`. [Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkh1tpo6/1/)

Comment: Yes, it is working approximately right. I want to get result without px only

Comment: @gstackoverflow `parseInt(document.getElementById('scrollbarY').style.height);`

Comment: @gstackoverflow - Use this ----> `document.getElementById('scrollbarY').style.height.slice(0, -2)` or Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try asking for the css value, ala:

```
$('#scrollbarY').css('height');
```

caveat: this will hand back a string representation with 'px' added, so you can parseInt($('#scrollbarY').css('height')) it. But another concern I would have is why the mismatch, is that div's height getting modified?

Comment: I've worked with jspScrollable before, and sometimes it adds values of multiple calls. But my first thought would be is that div getting modified? So, you could be inlining the height value, but of course, it is overwritten by jspScrollable plugin.

Comment: I want to get 105 at this situation

Comment: please check topic - I have added new details

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this

```
$('#scrollbarY').height();
```

### UPDATE

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axfd4t46/2/) I created with the above code. It shows the right height. Not really sure what you are doing unless we see more of your javascript code.

Comment: please check topic - I have added new details